# Trying to search through a message using Loops

Tags: python-2.7

I am trying to write a code that will search through a message

> the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog

and will continue to receive input from the user until the user inputs `exit`. I have to also define the above as a function that can be called repeatedly. Any help would be appreciated. Here is what I have.

```
message = 'the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog'

def search(keyWord):
    if raw_input('Please enter a word from the hidden phrase ') in message:
        print 'That word IS part of the message '
    else:
        print 'That word is NOT part of the message'


while True:
print 'Please try to guess the hidden phrase '
search('run')


print 'Thanks for guessing '
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
message = 'the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog'

def search(keyWord):
    if keyWord in message:
        print "That word IS part of the message. "
    else:
        print "That word is NOT part of the message"

print 'Please try to guess the hidden phrase '
while True:
    keyWord = raw_input("Please enter a word from the hidden phrase, or 'exit' to quit:")
    if keyWord == 'exit':
        break
    search(keyWord)    

print 'Thanks for guessing '
```

**Result**

```
>>> 
Please try to guess the hidden phrase 
Please enter a word from the hidden phrase, or 'exit' to quit:the
That word IS part of the message. 
Please enter a word from the hidden phrase, or 'exit' to quit:quick
That word IS part of the message. 
Please enter a word from the hidden phrase, or 'exit' to quit:quit
That word is NOT part of the message
Please enter a word from the hidden phrase, or 'exit' to quit:exit
Thanks for guessing 
>>>
```